# wp query order posts by custom taxonomy doesn't work correctly

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have custom wp query and i need to sort it according to taxonomy called 'consultation_records' which contains years 2017, 2018, 2019 etc.

I used this code but the result is the posts not ordered correctly i got for example 2021 > 2022 > 2023 > 2019 > 2017 > 2018

What i did wrong?

```
      <?php     $loop = new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'consultation_records',
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                  'orderby' => 'taxonomy',
                  'order' => 'DESC', 
                  'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(  'taxonomy' => 'consultation_year', 
                                            'field' => 'slug',
                                            'operator' => 'EXISTS',
                    ),),]);
        
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `'orderby' => 'taxonomy'` to `'orderby' => 'term_order'` should to the trick.

Comment: Still the same :/